# Is it possible to create a sticky table header with multiple rows inside it?

Tags: html, css

Given table provides a table head containing multiple rows. I already have a functional example for creating a table with a sticky table header, however when using multiple rows in the header, this solution will not do as some of the cells will disappear behind other cells.

[Sticky table](https://jsfiddle.net/cuxhdk69/):

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">#</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 1</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 2</th>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Handle</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              First
            </th>
            <th>
              Last
            </th>
            <th>
              First
            </th>
            <th>
              Last
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

According to the behaviour of my code above, the table head cells "Group 1" and "Group 2" will disappear behind the cells of the following row.

How could I avoid this from happening?

Comment: Anything here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673873/sticky-table-header-with-two-header-rows

Comment: It seems that Chrome dropped the development on this feature since ... I don't know. They put blame on the specification, but seem to not be able to fix some bugs with their scrolling engine. You should __stick__ (pun intended) to a polyfill for `display: sticky`, if you want to set `thead` to sticky

Answer (score 2):

Try the following changes in your css:

```
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

thead tr#row1 th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
}
thead tr#row2 th{
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
}
```

update your html file also

```
      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr id="row1">
          <th></th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 1</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 2</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr id="row2">
          <th>#</th>
            <th>
              First
            </th>
            <th>
              Last
            </th>
            <th>
              First
            </th>
            <th>
              Last
            </th>
          <th>Handle</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqpwxo1c/) for your solution.

Comment: Another solution (and I think it might be a better solution as well) would be rather using `nth-of-type()` rather than creating specific id's. I am kind of curious why Chrome requires the identification of row numbers to get this feature to work while on Firefox one could just set `position: sticky` on the `<thead>` instead.

Comment: yes but you have to specify the top property for each row you want to be sticky, what i did sometimes ago was to put the whole header group(consisting around 4 rows) to sticky and it worked but in your case its not

Answer (score 0):

You might add a class to your second row elements and add a top value:

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.second-row { 
  top: 34px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">#</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 1</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 2</th>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Handle</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="second-row">
              First
            </th>
            <th>
              Last
            </th>
            <th class="second-row">
              First
            </th>
            <th class="second-row">
              Last
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.example {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #afc8f0;
  text-align: center;
}

thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">#</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 1</th>
            <th scope="col" colspan="2">Group 2</th>
            <th scope="col" rowspan="2">Handle</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>
              First
            </th>
            <th>
              Last
            </th>
            <th>
              First
            </th>
            <th>
              Last
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <div class="example">
        ... Example ...
      </div>

      <!-- ...
        Some other elements
        .. -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```