# Problem on multiple table header (thead) rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table that has a sticky header. I need to add another row to header. It must be sticky as well. This is my css;

```
table tr th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 5;
  background: #fff;
}

table tr:nth-child(1) th {
  top: 0;
}

table tr:nth-child(2) th {
  top: 88px;
}
```

This works fine if the first rows height does not change. But it breaks if the height of first row changes. As the second child has a fixed top property.
Is there any way that I can make that value dynamic?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you add your html and make a snippet out of it

Comment: Is this ok for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673873/sticky-table-header-with-two-header-rows

Comment: Thank you I think it is gonna work.